# How to open a .txt file with autoit

Tags: autoit

I want to open a .txt file named "referral.txt" (location  :- "C:\Users\Niladri\Desktop".)
Then I want to copy the content. after that I want to create another .txt file named "copy.txt" and want to paste the previous content here. then I want to close both the files. Can you help me doing these guys? As I am new to autoit I need your help.

Comment: Not familiar with AutoIt besides the fact that I use a similar program to it. In any case, if you just need to copy the contents of the file, why not try copying the whole file instead and rename it? Based on a google search for `autoit copy file`, the first hit is `Function FileCopy`, which seems to fit the bill well.

Answer (score 1):

```
FileCopy('C:\Users\Niladri\Desktop\referral.txt', 'C:\Users\Niladri\Desktop\copy.txt', 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
;open and reading the file
$hFile = Fileopen("test.txt")
$FileContent = FileRead($hFile)
FileClose($hFile)

;writing the content to a new file 
Filewrite($FileContent,"Output.txt")
```

Answer (score -1):

ShellExecute ( @DesktopDir&"\File.txt","","","Open")